# CUDA out of memory while using pytorch lightning

Tags: pytorch, gpu, huggingface-transformers, ram, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to run a 3 Billion parameter `transformers` T5 model on a node with 4 V100 GPUs (16GB RAM on each GPU), and I'm getting the dreaded `torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory` error.  I'm using `lightning`, which is supposed to take care of boilerplate memory code, so it makes it hard to know where I'm going wrong.  I've tried just about every `deepspeed` strategy (argument of the `Trainer` object) there is, and none solves the problem.  I *should* be able to run the model on this node, I'm pretty sure.  Can anyone help me figure out what the issue is?

Is it that I need to use `deepspeed.checkpointing.checkpoint`?  I can't figure out how to use it in my case.

Below is some minimal code that can reproduce the issue.

```
#%% libraries
import torch
import lightning
import transformers
import deepspeed

from torch.optim import AdamW
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from lightning.pytorch import Trainer, LightningModule, LightningDataModule
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer


#%% data class
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, checkpoint):
        
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

        # fake data
        self.source_string = 'Apollo 10 (May 18–26, 1969) was a human spaceflight, the fourth crewed mission in the Apollo program of the United States, and the second (after Apollo 8) to orbit the Moon. NASA described it as a "dress rehearsal" for the first Moon landing[4] and designated it an "F" mission, intended to test all spacecraft components and procedures short of actual descent and landing. While astronaut John Young remained in the Command and Service Module (CSM) orbiting the Moon, astronauts Thomas Stafford and Gene Cernan flew the Apollo Lunar Module (LM) to within 14.4 kilometers (7.8 nmi) of the lunar surface, the point at which powered descent for landing would begin on a landing mission, before rejoining Young in the CSM. After orbiting the Moon 31 times, Apollo 10 returned safely to Earth; its success enabled the first crewed landing during the Apollo 11 mission two months later.'
        self.target_string = 'While NASA had considered attempting the first crewed lunar landing on Apollo 10, mission planners ultimately decided that it would be prudent to have a practice flight to hone the procedures and techniques. The crew encountered some problems during the flight: pogo oscillations during the launch phase and a brief, uncontrolled tumble of the LM ascent stage in lunar orbit during its solo flight. However, the mission accomplished its major objectives. Stafford and Cernan observed and photographed Apollo 11s planned landing site in the Sea of Tranquility. Apollo 10 spent 61 hours and 37 minutes orbiting the Moon, for about eight hours of which Stafford and Cernan flew the LM apart from Young in the CSM, and about eight days total in space. Additionally, Apollo 10 set the record for the highest speed attained by a crewed vehicle: 39,897 km/h (11.08 km/s or 24,791 mph) on May 26, 1969, during the return from the Moon.'
        
        self.source_strings = [self.source_string] * 100
        self.target_strings = [self.target_string] * 100
        
        self.source_tokens = [self.tokenizer(el, return_tensors = 'pt') for el in self.source_strings]
        self.target_tokens = [self.tokenizer(el, return_tensors = 'pt') for el in self.target_strings]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.source_strings)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.source_tokens[idx], self.target_tokens[idx]   

#%% lightning module
class MyLightningModule(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, checkpoint):
        super().__init__()

        self.language_model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):   
            source = batch[0]
            labels = batch[1].input_ids
            
            outputs = self.language_model(**source, labels = labels)
            #outputs = deepspeed.checkpointing.checkpoint(self.language_model, source.input_ids, source.attention_mask, labels)

            loss, logits = outputs[:2]  
            
            return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = deepspeed.ops.adam.FusedAdam(self.parameters(), lr = 1e-5)
        # optimizer = deepspeed.ops.adam.DeepSpeedCPUAdam(self.parameters(), lr = 1e-5)

        return optimizer

#%% instantiate
checkpoint = 'google/flan-t5-xl'
# checkpoint = 'google/flan-t5-base'

train_data = MyDataset(checkpoint)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, 
                          batch_size = 1, 
                          collate_fn = lambda x: x[0])

lightning_module = MyLightningModule(checkpoint)

trainer = Trainer(max_epochs = 2,
                  accumulate_grad_batches = 1,
                  accelerator = 'gpu',
                  devices = 4, 
                  strategy = 'deepspeed_stage_3',
                  enable_checkpointing = False,
                  precision = '32',
                 ) 
#%% run
trainer.fit(lightning_module, 
            train_dataloaders = train_loader)
```

For the `strategy` argument of the `Trainer`, I have tried `deepspeed_stage_2`, `deepspeed_stage_2_cpu_offload`, `deepspeed_stage_3`, `deepspeed_stage_3_cpu_offload`, `fsdp`, and `fsdp_cpu_offload`.  When using `cpu_offload` strategies, I switched the optimizer line of code to use `deepspeed.ops.adam.DeepSpeedCPUAdam`.

With a batch size of 1, precision set to 16, and using SGD, I am able to run the model, but I suspect I should be able to use the ADAM optimizers from `deepspeed`.

Comment: You said that you tried a number of things; can you tell us which ones because it helps understand the problem (and avoids folks suggesting something that you already tried)? Also, those V100s have what, 32GB of memory? Are you trying to simply run a pretrained model or train/finetune one? The latter uses a lot memory. And, if you are just trying to run a pretrained model, make sure you do it in `.eval()` mode.

Comment: @ATony Thanks for the suggested edits to my question.  Those were oversights on my part.  

Regarding training/evaluating, I *am* trying to finetune (actually both, but I can reproduce the issue simply with training).  I'd be hopeless if I coded up a `training_step` for evaluation.  But either way, my understanding is that the whole reason I switched from raw pytorch to pytorch lightning is that for most use cases, I don't need to mess with boilerplate code like `.eval()`.

Comment: Naively training that model on those GPUs is not going to happen. With weights represented as fp32, the model weights alone take up 12GB of memory. And one usually needs roughly twice that for training (finetuning is training), because one needs to store the intermediate activations and the optimizer overhead. You could try fp16 or mixed precision, and a simpler optimizer (e.g., SGD)... But, even if that works, it is going to be tight and you will have to use small batches.

Comment: My batch size is already 1, but switching to fp16 and SGD allowed me to run the model.  However, I don't see anyone using SGD, even with large models. I don't think my goals could be reasonably described as naively training on the GPUs. I'm trying to apply sharding techniques that are consistently described (https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/advanced/model_parallel.html#deepspeed-zero-stage-3) in a way that suggests a lot more performance can be squeezed out of my GPUs than I am succeeding at doing. I think I'm missing something in deepspeed—perhaps `deepspeed.checkpointing.checkpoint`